# CakePHP 3: Accessing current user in model

Tags: authentication, cakephp, logging, cakephp-3.0, audit-logging

Since i'm new to CakePHP, I have simple problems I cannot figure out.

I use CakePHP 3.4. I try to write a simple logger functionality. Every change applied to a record, I want to be logged to the ChangeLog model.

Using afterSave() event, I have following code:

```
public function afterSave($event, $entity, $options) {
  $logTable = TableRegistry::get('ChangeLogs');
  foreach ($entity->getDirty() as $key) {
    if($key != 'modified') {
      $record = $logTable->newEntity();
      $record->previous_value = $entity->getOriginal($key);
      $record->new_value = $entity[$key];
      $record->table_name = 'Stars';
      $record->column_name = $key;
      $record->row_id = $entity->id;
      $record->user_id = [what should i put here?]
      $record->user_id = $_SESSION['Auth']['user']['id'];
      $logTable->save($record);
    }
  }
```

It works well, but I also want to know which user performed operation and I don't know how can I obtain current user in the Model.

I try to avoid passing argument in controller, because I want user to be detected automaticly, and as a developer I don't want to remember about it every time I try change/add new functionalities in controller.

Answer (score 5):

Do not fiddle with superglobals directly in CakePHP, this will surely bite you at some point, especially in the test environment! Always use the abstracted methods (like [**the session object**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-session-object)) to access such data!

That being said, you could use events to inject the current user into the model callback/event flow. For example register globally to `Model.afterSave`, and pass the current user into the options.

Here's a basic example to demonstrate the principle. Imagine somthing like this in your app controller:

```
use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

// ...

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    // ...

    EventManager::instance()->on(
        'Model.afterSave',
        ['priority' => -1],
        function (Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, \ArrayObject $options) {
            // retrieve the user id from the auth component
            $options['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        }
    );
}
```

Given the priority of `-1` (the default priority is `10`) it will be invoked before the model callback for that event, so that in your table class you'll have access to `user_id` via the `$options` argument.

```
$record->user_id = $options['user_id'];
```

For something more reusable you'd probably use a custom listener class. Also check out events like `Auth.afterIdentify`, `Model.initialize`, and `Controller.intialize/startup`, these could be leaveraged to register your model events listener and to retrieve the current user.

See also

- **[Awesome CakePHP > Auditing / Logging](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#auditing--logging)**
- **[Cookbook > Events System](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Events System > Registering Listeners](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners)**
- **[Cookbook > Events System > Establishing Priorities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#establishing-priorities)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Lifecycle Callbacks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#lifecycle-callbacks)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Request Life-cycle Callbacks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks)**

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to allow you to pass the logged in user into the model layer:

https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint

It is not hooked into the model layer through events like the solution above.